# Retrieving values from mongodb with JSP

Tags: java, mongodb

Can anyone explain what's the mistake I made in this program.

I wrote a java class program for the connection named `dconnect.java.After`. Then I wrote a program in JSP and connect with mongodb, but the connection does not insert or retrieve any values to/from mongodb.

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
        pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"
        import="com.mongodb.BasicDBObject"
         import="com.mongodb.DB"
         import="com.mongodb.DBCollection"
         import="com.mongodb.DBCursor"
         import="com.mongodb.MongoClient"
         import="java.net.UnknownHostException"
         import="com.sun.org.apache.bcel.internal.generic.NEW"
         import="com.mongodb.DBObject"
         import="com.mongodb.Mongo"
         import="java.util.Date"
         import="myconnection.test.dconnect"%>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Insert title here</title>
    <!-- <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"> -->
    <meta name="keywords" content=" Employee-Profile " />
    <script src="latest/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="common/jquery/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="latest/js/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>jQuery Bootstrap Submenu Plugin Demo</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet"
        href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/css/bootstrap-submenu.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="docs.min.css">

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js" defer></script>
    <script
        src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        defer></script>
    <script src="dist/js/bootstrap-submenu.min.js" defer></script>
    <script src="docs.js" defer></script>

    <title>MAANTT | Employee-Profile</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
        href="common/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link href="/common/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-theme.css" rel="stylesheet"
        type="text/css" />
    <link href="/common/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css"
        rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="/common/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"
        type="text/css" />
    <link href="/common/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/common/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js">

    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript"
        src="/common/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js">

    </script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="common/css/new.css">
    <link href="common/css/new.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <link href="common/css/user_login.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />


    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {

            $('.btn-success').popover({
                title : "Header",
                content : "Blabla",
                placement : "bottom"
            });

        });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <%
    String signup=request.getParameter("signup");
    if(signup!=null)
    {
        //here is my logic for creating a user
        dconnect mymongo=dconnect.createInstance();
        DBCollection collection=mymongo.getCollection("users");
        BasicDBObject doc = new BasicDBObject();
        doc = new BasicDBObject();

            doc.append("email",request.getParameter("email"));
            doc.append("pwd",request.getParameter("pwd"));

            collection.insert(doc);
            session.setAttribute("email",request.getParameter("email"));
            response.sendRedirect("userlogin.jsp");
    }

    %>
    <jsp:include page="userloginheader.jsp" />
    //<form id="myform" name="myform" method="post"
            action="loggedin_homepage.jsp">
            <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="common/image/index.png"
                    style="margin-top: 3%; width: 100%">
            </div>

            <div class="container-fluid"
                style="margin-top: -120px; background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.07);">

                <div class=" col-md-5 col-xs-12">

                    <div class="panel panel-default" style="border: 2px solid #036ca0">
                        <div class="panel-heading"
                            style=" text-align:center; background-color: #FFFFFF; border: 2px solid #036ca0">Lets
                            Begin</div>


                        <div class="panel-body" style="background-color: #D0D0D0">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-8 "
                                        style="background-color: #D0D0D0">

                                        <input type="text"
                                            style="border: 2px solid #FFFFFF; background-color: 

    #D0D0D0; text-align: center;"
                                            required name="user" class="form-control" 

    id="name"
                                            placeholder="Email Address" maxlength="35">

                                    </div>

                                </div>
                                <br>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-8">

                                            <input type="password"
                                                style="border: 2px solid #FFFFFF; 

    background-color: #D0D0D0; text-align: center;"
                                                class="form-control" name="pwd" 

    id="password" style="border:"
                                                placeholder="Password" maxlength="25">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-lg-offset-2 col-lg-8 col-xs-12 ">
                                            <button type="submit" name="signup" id="button"
                                                class="buttonAdd btn btn-sm btn-primary 

    btn-block">Sign
                                                up</button>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    </div>


                                    <hr>
                                    <div class="footer">
                                        <div class="col-md-offset-2" >By clicking sign up you
                                            agree to  user agreement and privacy policy</div>

                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>


                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: you are loading too much jquery files..

Comment: bootstrap doesn't retrieve value from any database..

Comment: then what's the solution for that

Comment: you should use client side javascript for that

Comment: Your example code includes lots and lots of padding which likely has nothing to do with your problem and makes it very hard to read. Please try to reduce it to a [Short, Self Contained, Compilable, Example](http://www.sscce.org). When I don't read anything further from you I will assume that you found your mistake yourself while doing so.